# Mac app to convert Markdown to Web

Tags: markdown, macos, document-converter

I am looking for a Mac app to convert/publish my Markdown text simply into the cloud.
Something like this online tool: http://markdowntoweb.com 
But I would rather use a native macOS app, preferabely with more functinality, like preview, edit, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One popular option is [Jekyll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jekyll_(software)):

- cross platform
- open-source and free
- CLI

Answer (score 0):

A very nice alternative to Jekyll is the python [Hyde](http://hyde.github.io/) static website generator.

- Cross Platform
- Free, Gratis & Open-Source
- CLI
- Support for powerful template languages like [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/) complemented with custom tags and filters
- Simple installation: `sudo pip install -U hyde`
- Create a site template: `hyde -s /path/to/your/site create`
- Generate your site:

  `cd /path/to/your/site`

  `hyde gen`
- Instant preview in your browser using built-in webserver that regenerates content if needed:

  `cd /path/to/your/site`

  `hyde serve`

The demo above produces a "Basic" layout which looks like:
[image]